# Excel - Display range of numbers, with dynamic exclusions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a way to dynamically create a range of numbers to display based on their presence.
Lets say I have cells A1-10 and B1-10. Value in A1 is 1, A2 is 2, A3 is 3.... A10 is 10.  The B values will do a countif to see if that number is present somewhere else.

A1 - 1
A2 - 2
A3 - 3
A4 - 4
A5 - 5
A6 - 6
A7 - 7
A8 - 8
A9 - 9
A10 - 10

B1 - 1
B2 - 1
B3 - 1
B4 - 0
B5 - 1
B6 - 1
B7 - 1
B8 - 1
B9 - 1
B10 - 1

In the example above, I would like the output to be 1-3,5-10, omitting 4 because the value is 0 in B4.  However this could change next time.  B4 could be 1 and B7 could be 0, making it look like 1-6,8-10.
I then need to add that to a concatenate it to read something like "Range 1-3,5-10".

Comment: is there always a single 0 or could you have "range 1-2,4-6,7-10"

Comment: There will always be a number, no zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following formula :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, SCAN(0,B1:B10,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x,x+1)))+1,
     b, FILTER(HSTACK(A1:A10,a),B1:B10),
     c, DROP(b,,1),
     IFERROR("Range "&ARRAYTOTEXT(DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(c),LAMBDA(d,e,VSTACK(d,
      LET(w,TAKE(FILTER(b,c=e),,1),u,MIN(w),v,MAX(w),IF(u=v,u,u&"-"&v))))),1)),"None"))
```

---

Test Cases :

One

[image]

---

Two

[image]

---

Three

[image]

---

Edit : Updated As Per Comments of OP -->

> *@MayukhBhattacharya thanks again for the help, im looking to modify it*
> *slightly and cant figure out where/how to do so. i was looking for it*
> *to display something like Range 1-5, 7-10. However I need it to say*
> *Range 1-5, Range 7-10. What do i need to modify for that?*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, SCAN(0,B1:B10,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x,x+1)))+1,
     b, FILTER(HSTACK(A1:A10,a),B1:B10),
     c, DROP(b,,1),
     IFERROR(ARRAYTOTEXT("Range "&DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(c),LAMBDA(d,e,VSTACK(d,
     LET(w,TAKE(FILTER(b,c=e),,1),u,MIN(w),v,MAX(w),IF(u=v,u,u&"-"&v))))),1)),"None"))
```

---

Comment: Maybe revise to account for cases where your formula would output, for example, `Range 1-1, 5-6, 8-10`? Perhaps the OP would prefer `Range 1, 5-6, 8-10`?

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir thank you, Sir is it correct now? can i make it bit shorter. Thanks

Comment: Good work! Now maybe just account for the case where `B1:B10` are all zero.

Comment: @JosWoolley Sir, `IFERROR()` would be fine, but will it happen that all the `B1:B10` is `zero`, what do you say. Done Sir. Thanks again for guidance.

Comment: Experience has taught me to always deal with such cases, no matter how unlikely!

Comment: Thank you very much sir, highly appreciate your knowledge and experience, thank you again!

Comment: This looks great!  i'll play around with it in my xls and tweak it as needed. There is zero chance i would have come up with that. Thanks. stay tuned.

Comment: Also, 98% of the time there will only be 1 number left out, maybe 2.

Comment: @Tarelis gotya, nevermind, we have taken every aspect into account, ofcourse with the help of Jos Sir, who have suggested some important points

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you very much for the assistance on this!!

Comment: @Tarelis glad to know it worked perfect. =)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thanks again for the help, im looking to modify it slightly and cant figure out where/how to do so. 
i was looking for it to display something like Range 1-5, 7-10. However I need it to say Range 1-5, Range 7-10.  What do i need to modify for that?

Comment: This `"Range "&` has to be after `ARRAYTOTEXT()`

Comment: @Tarelis please refer my updated answer